# OSX not using latest Ruby version

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

When I try to run a ruby command in terminal I get an error:

```
Ruby >= 2.1.9 required to run app (You have 2.0.0)
```

When I try

```
brew upgrade ruby
```

I get

```
Error: ruby 2.3.1 already installed
```

Previously I tried installing ruby with rvm

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Maybe I have two different versions of ruby running?

How can I get my system to use the latest version of ruby?

EDIT: Definitely two versions installed

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin14]
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

My $PATH seems correct?

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory
```

EDIT2 specifying the full path to the correct version of ruby:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby app.rb
/usr/local/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- app (LoadError)
```

Comment: You may have too many Ruby installers on your system and they're running into conflict. I'd recommend using [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) as it's a lot less messy than RVM, and avoid installing Ruby directly with `brew`. What does `which ruby` say? How about `gem env`? If you're using `rvm` then `rvm versions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest cases, you can just specify the fully-qualified PATH to your Homebrew-installed Ruby. For example:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby /path/to/foo.rb
```

However, if you need to require gems or libraries, you need to step up your game with a Ruby version manager such as chruby, rvm, or rbenv. You should *never* replace the system ruby, and managing all the environments variables, gems, and so forth that Ruby needs without a version manager is outside the scope of a reasonable Stack Overflow question.

Comment: When I specify the full path I get: No such file or directory -- app.rb (LoadError)

Comment: @stef I already addressed that. Perhaps you aren't specifying the full path to your source file. On the other hand, if you're trying to `require` anything, you need to step up to a version manager, or manage all the [environment variables](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/rubyworld.html) and gem directories yourself.

Comment: Something like RVM? Homebrew can't do this? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the `homebrew` version 2.3.1 of Ruby, but you are not using it because you haven't set your PATH correctly.

Try using the one `homebrew` installed for you by adding `/usr/local/bin` to the start of you PATH, or by running:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

I guess if you use the Apple-supplied Ruby in `/usr/bin` you will get:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
```

Comment: My $PATH: -bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory - correct, right?

Comment: Your shims path should definitely come first to get ruby running using the rbenv logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall ruby from brew and just use rvm.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple version installed than you can use rvm to make ruby 2.3.1 your default: `rvm --default use 2.1.1`