# Bundle install leads to Gemfile error: unexpected ':', expecting $end gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins

Tags: ruby, parse-platform, rubygems, bundler

UPDATE1.

Added the line `ruby '2.4.0'` to my `Gemfile` and now the bundler complains about old ruby version:

```
$ bundle
Your Ruby version is 1.8.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0
```

However:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

So it looks like [`bundler`](https://bundler.io/) is using my old ruby version that was originally installed by the OSX, instead of the new one that I installed via `homebrew`.

Is there any way to tell the `bundler` to use the new ruby?

---

UPDATE.

I have changed line 3 of `Gemfile` as suggested in the answer by Sachin Singh, unfortunately that leads to further errors:

```
...
Installing i18n (0.7.0) 
Gem::InstallError: i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occurred while installing i18n (0.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The installation `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'` goes without errors but the problem persists.

---

I am trying to [setup Parse Docs locally](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Docs#running-the-site-locally) but

```
$ bundle install
```

leads to this error:

```
Gemfile syntax error:
/Users/dmitrizaitsev/Repos/Parse-Docs/Gemfile:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
                          ^
```

My Ruby version is 2.4:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

[Their Gemfile](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/docs/blob/gh-pages/Gemfile):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'jekyll', '>=3.1.6'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
gem 'jekyll-redirect-from', '0.10.0'
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: please add your gemfile.

Comment: @SachinSingh added, thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be its a ruby version issue, you can try this:

```
ruby '2.4.0'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'jekyll', '>=3.1.6'
gem 'github-pages', :group => 'jekyll_plugins'
gem 'jekyll-redirect-from', '0.10.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but unfortunately, there are further errors, see the update.

Comment: are you using rvm?

Comment: No, I have just upgraded Ruby directly with `brew`

Comment: I think your ruby < 1.9.3 as you can see the errors. `Gem::InstallError: i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.`

Comment: But `ruby -v` gives version 2.4 as I mentioned in the question

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev try specifying ruby version in gemfile like above.

Comment: see this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397874/osx-not-using-latest-ruby-version